# Creating a counter in R using a loop

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R and searched the forums and did not find an answer to this question.  I am trying to create a loop in R that counts whether a condition is met between 2 rows in a dataframe.  I understand that this is not an efficient way to do this but it is for a class assignment.  My problem is that my code is creating an endless loop rather giving me the counter output and it is unclear to me how to fix it.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.  The code is below:

```
counter=0
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe))
  {if (dataframe$column1[i]>dataframe$column2[i]==TRUE)
{
counter=counter+1}
}
print(counter)
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code, but it would be helpful if you could share the dataframe as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how many times your column 1 is higher than column 2, you don't have to use a loop :

```
counter <- sum(dataframe$column1>dataframe$column2)
```

`sum(dataframe$column1>dataframe$column2)` gives you a vector of length `nrow(dataframe)` with `TRUE` and `FALSE` when the condition is verified, and R do this element by element with vectores.

Then when you `sum` it, `TRUE` is considered as a 1 and `FALSE` as a 0. So it gives you how many times the condition is verified beetween the two columns.

Comment: I appreciate the concise solution using the sum command but I need to do this assignment using control flow which is why I was using a loop.  The columns in the dataframe that I am referencing have both numbers and empty values.  I modified the code above by putting a print(counter)  statement in the line below the counter =counter+1 but when I run the loop I get no output rather than the current counter.  It is unclear to me what I am doing wrong so would greatly appreciate any additional suggestions